# cPanel cron job not working for php script

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I want to run a php script in every 1 minute using cron job from cPanel. It will generate a cache file from a video list from a CDN. But it seems I am doing an issue, so this code is not generating any cache file as I am looking for.

Here is the php file. Pointing my problem is highly appreciated :-) And this is my first try in cron job.

```
<?php 
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/../templates/site/header.php');
?>
<?php
    $li = 'xxxxxx';
    $lk = 'xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx';
?>

<!-- get video info -->
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');

function generateCacheKey($li) {
    return "videos_{$li}";
}

function getData($li, $page, $lk)
{
    $cacheKey = generateCacheKey($li);
    $cacheFile = __DIR__ . "/../public/cache/{$cacheKey}.json";

    try {
        // Check if the cache file exists and is not expired (e.g., use a TTL)
        $cacheTTL = 24 * 60 * 60; 
        if (file_exists($cacheFile) && time() - filemtime($cacheFile) < $cacheTTL) {
            $jsonResponse = file_get_contents($cacheFile);
            $data = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
        } else {
            // If not in cache or expired, make the API request
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://video.bunnycdn.com/library/' . $li . '/videos', [
                'query' => [
                    'page' => $page,
                    'itemsPerPage' => '1000',
                    'orderBy' => 'date',
                ],
                'headers' => [
                    'AccessKey' => $lk,
                    'accept' => 'application/json',
                ],
            ]);

            $jsonResponse = $response->getBody();
            $data = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);

            file_put_contents($cacheFile, $jsonResponse);
        }

        return $data;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Log the error to a file in the same directory
        $errorLog = __DIR__ . "/../public/error.log";
        error_log("Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n", 3, $errorLog);

        // You may choose to handle the error in other ways as well
        return false;
    }
}

$page = 1;

if ($li !== "") {
    $data = getData($li, $page, $lk);

    // Check if there was an error retrieving data
    if ($data === false) {
        // Handle the error, display a message, redirect, etc.
        echo "Error retrieving data. Please try again later.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: First question is: Does your PHP script not run or do what it is supposed to do, or does your cron job not execute the script every minute? Those are two very different things and I can't tell what is the case from your question.

Comment: I tried with a simple mail sender code in same file, it works well. But only when I try to run this code block, it is not working as expected. It must generate a cache file in every one minute. But it is not doing anything.

Comment: So then, have you done any [debugging](https://www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/) to find out what it _is_ doing? You might have to log things line by line, if necessary. And make sure PHP error logging is enabled.

Comment: Maybe you can see in my code that I am trying to generate any error log. But somehow it is not generating any error log also. PHP error logging is enabled in cPanel

Comment: In my previous response, I mentioned that, I inserted a simple mail sender code in the same file, to check my environment is working or not, And it worked well and it sends mail in every 1 minute. 

But when I insert this code block, it is not acting anything. I think I am doing any mistake in this script that is not supported by cron job system. I am trying to figure this problem out.

Comment: Well, calling a PHP script from a browser is different from calling a script from within Linux with a cron job. Some things aren't present in the latter environment. It could, for instance, be that your template file `header.php` generates an error and the code in your question doesn't get executed. Did you check the error log for PHP error messages?

Comment: Mind you, we still don't know if this is a cron job problem, meaning your script doesn't get called at all, or a PHP script error, meaning the script has an bug and doesn't properly execute.

Comment: Hohoo. its working bro. I just removed the unnecessary header file. And bang! I think the header was the problem. But I don't know why. Maybe it is containing some other files path that was not suitable for cron job environment.

Comment: OK, nice. You could learn from this by finding out why the `header.php` script failed. Did you check the error logs? In general, when a PHP script doesn't work, the first thing you do is [look in the error logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php-5-apache-fastcgi-and-cpanel). Error messages are super useful.